# sudoless passwordless script

Tags: bash, sudo, sudoers

I want to make a sudoless passwordless script which doesn't prompt for password to any user executing that script.

*Problem*: my script contains `rsync` utility to send files to a backup server, but i always get `permission denied error` when the folder which needs to be send contains some files for which the `access` is set to none. whereas other files are also owned by root but their `access` is set to read only. I'm using public key authentication to send files to destination/backup so that it doesn't prompt for password input but it cannot send access protected files like above without sudo and password input.

*Tries*: I tried https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229653/332764 this solution but it is not working. Still same error is there.

EDIT: **sudoers file**

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

ortega ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/usr/path/transmit_ckpnt.sh
# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: The solution in [that unix.se question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229653/332764) allows you to run the script *with* `sudo`, but without requiring a password. When you tested it, did you use `sudo`?

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes i've tested it with sudo. then i've to enter the password to make it work. without sude it didn't worked corrctly, gave the same error for the protected file.

Comment: In theory, you could use a setuid script. This is like pointing a loaded cannon towards your house and hoping nobody pulls the trigger.

Comment: @tripleee explain more please. what can i do with this in this case?

Comment: Write a *really really* secure script in a language which allows you to do that. Probably limit it to just the `rsync` part with hard-coded paths etc. Make `root` the owner and `chmod` the [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit. Done.

Comment: If you needed the password, then the entry you made in /etc/sudoers isn't right. BTW, be sure to use the `visudo` command to edit it, to keep from misformatting it and rendering `sudo` unusable.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I've shared the sudoers files in the question , pls have a look at it.

Comment: @tripleee still doesn't work

Comment: "Still doesn't work" is not very precise. I'm guessing you skipped the "in a language which allows you to do that" part, which excludes shell script. Probably post your attempt as a separate question [with proper diagnostics](/help/how-to-ask) if you can't figure it out. But I'll repeat again that this is probably a very bad idea unless you know *precisely* what you are doing.

Comment: oh i used shell command to first `chown` the script and then did `chmod u+s`. Then which language should i have to use?

Comment: @ram I think you copied that sudoers entry too literally -- the "ortega" part is the username that's allowed to use that entry, so if that's not your username it won't have any effect. Change it to the username that backups will be run from.

Comment: If you are not having `root` access, then I don't think it's possible, I encountered same problem  some time ago, I used  `rsync` with public key authentication and was running everything as root      using `sudo -i`,  then only it worked.  It never prompted for password for sending permission protected files as I was running as root. Try this if you have root access.

Comment: @y_159 yes that's how i did it.

Comment: Do you have the `admin` and/or `sudo` group created and are the users you want to be able to run without password members of one or both groups?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Setup a root crontab job to do a `chown` (Have root do a job periodically)
2. Use [docker privilege escalation](https://gtfobins.github.io/gtfobins/docker/) to `chmod` your file in a container with a mounted volume.
3. Devise a non-root task equivalent to the root one you are doing

### 1. Root crontab

A [crontab](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/crontab.htm) schedules commands execution at Specified time or time interval. Here you could create a [root crontab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127732/system-crontab-or-root-crontab) with the command `sudo crontab -u root -e`. This will open you into an editor to write your crontab: [best practices](https://www.jefframnani.com/writing-a-good-cron-job/)

### 2. Docker privilege escalation

This method requires either already being `root` or being part of a machines [docker group](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/). As a non-root user who is a member of the docker group you have the ability to mount any directory as a volume within a docker container. Within the container you are root, and changes you make to the mounted volume will persist. Simply `chmod` the file in the container.

#### File Permissions

- Use [chown](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) and [chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) to change [file-system permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions).

#### Password-less rsync

- The [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) command supports using [ssh-keys](https://andykdocs.de/development/Linux/2013-01-17+Rsync+over+SSH+with+Key+Authentication) which allow you to log into other machines password-less after a quick one time key-exchange.

If you cannot `chown` or `chmod` a file because of a permission error, that is because a user with more permissions than you (root) will need to help you change the file permissions.

Comment: I've to repeatedly do this that's why i want to automate this and don't want to be prompted everytime for password input, even if i use `chmod` everytime before `rsync`, i still have to enter the password. is there any way can do chmod without entering password? i think it comes back again to this question.

Comment: I've updated the post to expand on a `crontab` approach to get root to periodically do a task requiring `root` and a `docker` approach which to be honest, is a bit of a hack, but could be made as part of a script

Comment: crontab will run the task at satrtup, my problem deals with a period of 50ms, i.e a new folder is added to a specific folder periodically and it contains a file for which while rsyncing it throws the above error.

Comment: A crontab could execute as frequently as one a minute. The docker volume mount is simply one command and could be executed wherever/whenever you’d like

Answer (score 0):

I use this Sudoless no password bash script

```
1. Open the /etc/sudoers file (as root, of course!) by running:
sudo nano /etc/sudoers

2. At the end of the /etc/sudoers file add this line:
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```